# Exclude VMWare adapters from IPConfig list?

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

I am using VMWare Workstation my laptop.

When entering `ipconfig` in cmd I get all network interfaces.

Is there a way to have it so that it only shows me my real network interfaces, without VMWare interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

One of the closest thing you can achieve with a one-liner without having to write a script would be:

```
@netsh interface show interface | @findstr /v VMware | findstr Enabled > "%TEMP%\tmpip.txt" && @for /f "tokens=4" %a in (%TEMP%\tmpip.txt) do @netsh interface ip show config name=%a
```

This will NOT show the MAC, but I am not sure what you wanted to get except to exclude the VMware adapters.

What it does:

1. creates a temporary file with the adapter names excluding VMware acquired with the netsh command
2. retrieves ip information for all adapters from temporary file with the netsh command

The ipconfig command allows adapter names only with

- renew
- release
- renew6
- release6
- showclassid
- setclassid
- showclassid6
- setclassid6

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same result with PowerShell, plus filtering is alot easier:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME | Where-Object {$_.description -notlike "VMware*"}
```

Where `$env:COMPUTERNAME` is the hostname of the localmachine, change this another hostname to query remote machines.